# How well would cat-5/6 work as a multi pair audio cable?

Tags: analog, wiring

I'm looking at a situation where I'd want to connect a number of devices together to pass line level analog audio signals around. For the connections in question, there will always be small groups of channels (I've been assuming groups of 4) that go together. So rather than require a big mess of patch cables, I'm wondering what existing off the shelf items would work. 1m Cat-5/6 patch cords are easy to get and would have the correct number of conductors and meets the mechanical requirements but how would it do for signal quality?

---

*Edit 1*: I'm not sure that I didn't introduce some confusion here. I haven't settled on what kind of signaling I'm going to be using other than that it doesn't inherently need to deliver any power (the component at the other end will have whatever amps are needed to avoid that).

*Edit 2*: In the case I'm considering, I would be building the devices at each end and one of the advantages I'm seeing to using Cat5 is that I can use a single RJ-45 jack rather than four 1/4in TRS or XLR jacks (one of the devices could easily be limited by panel space for  jacks).

Comment: It would work well, or at least for your back pocket: http://www.amazon.com/Denon-AKDL1-Dedicated-Link-Cable/dp/B000I1X6PM/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Comment: That cable is for the "purest digital audio", not always great for line level analog audio.

Comment: Look at the price tag. $999.99.

Comment: ohhhhhhh, didnt see that. nice :)

Comment: An audiophool is born every minute.

Comment: $999.99?  Dang, it went up - used to be $500.  Times are tough.

Comment: That is the refurb price. The new price is $9,999

Comment: @Thomas O, I have been in the pro-audio line since I was 15, I was never around anyone who exposed me to things like that though.

Answer (score 7):

Should be fine over short distances.  If the cable is going to be in a noisy environment (lots of 50/60hz EM especially) go with shielded CAT5 and make sure the shield is grounded properly.

If your looking at longer distances, consider differential signaling, which again the twisted pairs of a cat5 cable are just fine for.

As always when dealing with patching devices together like this be careful of creating ground loops.

Comment: I agree. I think cat5 will get the job done, shielding cannot hurt, only connect it on one side.

Comment: Luckily, STP is a standard item.

Comment: @Kortuk: That's an interesting thought, I wonder if a ground disconnect switch at each jack would be a good idea?

Comment: A switch on the aux device is typically what I have seen, but not one at the main device.

Comment: You want to ground the shield on the sending end of the link normally when its a 1 way link.  You may want to plan ahead for ground loops if you know up front the various devices have very different ground potentials (separate virtual grounds).  However, if your inputs are isolated well you should be fine.  Normally on an audio input i'll use an opamp in a differential configuration even if the incoming signal isn't differential.  This keeps the input ground from ever touching the device's ground.

Comment: Always use differential signaling.

Comment: Ideally, you have the shield connected at both ends, at least at RF frequencies, and then the differential signaling and balanced impedances takes care of any interference or ground loops.

Comment: @endolith you've confused your problems, at RF frequencies you shield to keep your signals from radiating EMI that could violate FCC, not to prevent noise entering the system (at least at RF frequencies).  Also at that point you ground at both ends to minimize inductance to ground.

Comment: You also want to prevent RF from entering the system, since it can be demodulated by nonlinear circuit elements and get into your audio.  http://www.rane.com/note165.html

Comment: that link doesn't talk about using shielding to keep RF EMI out.  It talks about improperly terminated shields acting as RF antennas which is a very much a concern.  However if the shield simply weren't there, its very doubtful there would be an RF pick up problem.  Quite a few times i've seen shields _cause_ RF noise problems in audio circuits due to poor implementation.

Comment: So, connect the sheathing to ground at both ends through a capacitor sized to pass somewhere around 0.25MHz and above?

Comment: I would at least include a some sort of disconnect to allow you to play with connecting at only one end.  Connecting at both ends if fine as long as it doesn't case a ground loop, which is often does.  Also the ideal path from the shield to system ground is the one with the lowest resistance _AND_ lowest inductance.  It also shouldn't go through the circuit board.  Which really just means it should be tied to the chassis as soon as possible and the chassis should be tied directly to the system ground.

Comment: Well most RJ-45 jack mount on PCBs (or in wall plates but those are way to big) so I gues going through the PCB is going to be hard to avoid. OTOH, having a "grounded" board mount right next to it that is only used for the shielding should be somewhat close to a direct ground.

Comment: well, when i mean "through" i mean not having the ground return path going all the way across the PCB.  With board mount connectors the common way to handle it is to take the shield ground to the nearest chassis mounting screw, which is usually designed to be close to the connectors partially for this reason.  This gives you a pretty direct path to chassis ground without running all over the PCB.  Just keep the traces or copper pour from the connector to the screw as short and fat as possible.

Comment: Placing the board mounts near the jacks is a good idea from a mechanical standpoint as well. I think I see where this is leading.

Comment: Yep :) The place where shielding gets really complicated is when your stuck with non conductive enclosures.  Usually results in awkward ground strategies like a "chassis" ground around the edge of the PCB which isn't all that great from a number of stand points.

Comment: Or do what physicist do, wrap it in a ball of aluminum foil: http://www.reciprocalspace.net/files/dbdcc47f0f7492f83d42dc49c93ddbd4-59.html

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen in radio stations, they work well.

The audio is differential and the twisted pair removes common mode noise.

Comment: So it's actually used by people who know what they are doing?

Comment: I would think radio stations would use balanced xlr everywhere. If they are using CAT5 it is probably because it got converted to digital.

Comment: They are running analog audio over the CAT5.  It's cheaper, available, and works.  The only difference between CAT5 and Balanced XLR are the connectors and the shield.

Comment: XLR is +, -, gnd, and shield. The combination of all of the pins make for really low noise. How would you map this to cat5? Also, in his case he has gnd and + audio which is not necessarily differential nor is it very well protected against noise.

Comment: If he's doing single-ended signals, then there is going to have problems.  I'd start by going to balanced audio signals.

Comment: I haven't chosen a signaling yet. See edit.

Comment: Choose balanced and differential for long lines.

Comment: @endolith: How long is long? I'm not expecting anything longer than a meter, two at the outside.

Comment: @BCS: I'd consider that short, but I think the official definition of long if a function of the EMI noise frequency/strength you are worried about.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the gauge of cat5 seems to be too small of diameter for line level audio. It may work just fine but you might want to consider something like this: http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?Partnumber=240-286

Comment: Cat5 comes in many gages. What size is needed for line level stuff? It's not like I'll be driving any power through it. The kind of patch cord used to connect computer speakers to sounds cards can't be much bigger.

Comment: Also, one of the reason I'm looking for a multi channel cable it to reduce the real estate the jacks take up.

Comment: I was confused as to what you were asking. I was under the assumption you had prebuilt equipment and were going to solder connectors to the CAT5. In the case where you are soldering connectors on, since the wire is so small, it tends to break off easily when getting beat around like many connectors do.

Comment: If you are building both ends yourself then I think you can easily get away with CAT5 cable. If you are worried about noise you can create a differential signal to put on the lines. (Example: http://sound.westhost.com/project51.htm)